# Can a compound index be used in searching a single field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

If I create the following compound index:

`{'username': 1, 'uid': 1}`

Can this index be used if I only search with `uid`, like
`db.users.find({'uid': '12345'})` ?

Because generating two separate single indexes seems to use more memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as you are querying by fields that are a left subset of the indexed fields, MongoDB will automatically use the index.  That is, if you have an index like {a:1, b:1, c:1}, all the 3 queries db.coll.find({a:"xxx"}), db.coll.find({a:"xxx", b:"yyy"}) and db.coll.find({a:"xxx", b:"yyy", c:"zzz"}) will make use of this index, assuming there are no other indexes.

Comment: but what if I skip `a` and query `b` instead?

Comment: @MK, If you query b, the index will not be used.  That is, db.coll.find({b:"yyy"}) will not use the index {a:1, b:1, c:1}.  The query can only an index starting with b.

Comment: @Sammaye, I didn't quite get you.  Is my answer incorrect or misleading?

Comment: Your answer applies if he wasn't gong by the second field in the index, as his comment states

Comment: My comment explains how indexes work in MongoDB.  I think that clarifies his specific question and also helps understand the general concept.  If you don't think so, please feel free to down vote.

Answer (score 1):

It can by using `hint()` however, the optimiser will not pick this index by default because it searches by prefix and `uid` is not a prefix of `{username, uid}`.

As for using the index when searching, it will scan all `username` values and then scan for the `uid` in each username.

This can sometimes be a good thing, especially if you want to sort those `uid` values by `username`, since `scanandorder` will be `false` but if you are not expecting to sort by the `username` fields then you could find that it could get a bit unperformant.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, mongo will not use this compound index when you find by uid.

Your index will be used when you will try to find by username or by pair username and uid.
It is well described in mongo documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes

If you prefer searching by uid instead of username, you should switch order in your compound index.

If you do not search by username and uid simultaneously, best option is to drop this compound index and create two separated indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If your index: {a:1,b:1,c:1}.

Then, it will apply for below conditions:

```
db.coll.find({a:'xxx'})
db.coll.find({b:'yyyy'})
db.coll.find({c:'zzz'})
db.coll.find({a:'xxx',c:'zzz'})
db.coll.find({a:'xxx',b:'yyy'})
db.coll.find({a:'xxx',b:'yyy',c:'zzz'})
db.coll.find({b:'yyy',a:'xxx',c:'zzz'})
db.coll.find({b:'yyy',c:'zzz',a:'xxx'})
```

It will not work in the below conditions:

```
db.coll.find({b:'yyy',c:'zzz'})
db.coll.find({b:'yyy'})
db.coll.find({c:'zzz'})
```

Indexes are working only if your index prefix is in your search query. Order doesn't matter.